# Java Do-While loop

Tags: java

I want to prompt the user if they wanna continue (y/n) but my code is just repeating to my ans y. how do I modify the code to the loop? appreciate for the help thanks

````
``` public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String grade = "";
    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userInput = "";

    do{
    System.out.print("Enter your serial no: ");
    int serial = kb.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Score: ");
    int score = kb.nextInt();


    if(score<0||score>100){
        System.out.println("Invalid Score");
    }else if(score>84){
        grade = "A";
        System.out.println("Your grade is: "+grade);
    }else if(score>74){
        grade = "B";
        System.out.println("Your grade is: "+grade);
    }else if(score>64){
        grade = "C";
        System.out.println("Your grade is: "+grade);
    }else if(score>49){
        grade = "D";
        System.out.println("Your grade is: "+grade);
    }else{
        grade = "F";
        System.out.println("Your grade is: "+grade);
    }

        System.out.println("Do you want to continue y/n");
        userInput = input.nextLine();


    }while(input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    input.close();```
````

Comment: Change `while(input.next().equalsIgnoreCase("y"));` to `while(userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));` Otherwise your code is not doing what you think it should be doing, and you're getting extra input unnecessarily.

Comment: Hi I did and it still the same. it keep prompting me do you want to continue (y/n), if I enter y. it show me do you want to continue (y/n) again

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake on code. You got value on userInput field but you didn't use it.
You must remove this line:

```
userInput = input.nextLine();
```

It will resolve your problem